# android xml SOAP response

Tags: android, xml, web-services, parsing, soap

I have the Following SOAP response returned from a .NET SOAP Server.

```
(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetCategoriesIMFollowing_WithTokenResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetCategoriesIMFollowing_WithTokenResult>8,9,10,11,12,2</GetCategoriesIMFollowing_WithTokenResult>
        </GetCategoriesIMFollowing_WithTokenResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>).
```

I need to parse it in order to get the integers (8,9,10,11,12,2)

What is the easiest way to just get these numbers ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what i need in this link

http://www.whatsoniphone.com/blog/android-app-development-parsing-web-service-response-part-1/#

thank you.